# Tensorflow installation gets stuck at 100%

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install tensorflow using `pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow` command. Installation gets stuck at 100%.

> Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/27/a6e7dcb8ae20a4dbf3725321058923fec262b6f7835179d78ccc8d98deec/h5py-2.9.0.tar.gz (287kB)
>
> 100% |████████████████████████████████| 296kB 4.4MB/s

downloading stuck at the above line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need these dependencies before installing Tensorflow:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev 
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev
sudo apt-get install gfortran
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-h5py
```

Then, run:

```
wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v1.8.0/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl

cp /home/USER/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl

sudo pip3 install tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```